# Create a part of `Express` Web application as an `Angular` app

Tags: node.js, angular, express, routes

In the past few weeks I've setup a small website using `Node` and `Express`. The routing is done via express and the website consists of the root route as **(http://localhost:3000/)** and some sub routes like `/contact` or `/login` and so on.

Now I want to create an angular app as a part of that express app. So I want to create that angular app running on the sub-route (localhost:3000/dashboard) of the whole website.

**How can that be done and solved?**

The routes of the angular app should be managed either by the `Express` app or the `Angular` app?

Hope anyone can help me.

Comment: So do you want to use express as an API..?

Comment: @MikeOne I'm using express to render the html pages. As the pages I've done until now are static pages I was using HTML and CSS to create them. For the dashboard I think using Angular would be easier.

Comment: I mean using Angular would be easier because I'll be using Firebase's Real Time Database where it should be able to load data from the database and update the rendered content instantly.

Comment: Ah gotcha.. angular + firebase rtdb works nicely indeed! So you’d need to be able to serve the application files (js+css) and the angular index.html.. you could simply put all this inside the dashboard folder and setup express to serve the files..

Comment: On the other hand, rtdb also pretty easy to use from node itself.. but then your visitors won’t get the advantages pf the ‘realtime’ part of it..